# How to print values of an object in Java when you do not have the source code for the class?

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class MyClass {
        ClassABC abc = new ClassABC();
}
```

I just have a .class file of ClassABC. I want to print all the public, private, protected and default field values of "abc" object. How can I do this using Reflection?

Comment: Look at the  ReflectionToStringBuilder from apache way

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can get all fields by [`Class#getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29). Each returns a [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) object of which you in turn can use the [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method to obtain the value. To get the values for non-public fields, you only need to set [`Field#setAccessible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) to `true`.

So, in a nut:

```
ClassABC abc = new ClassABC();
for (Field field : abc.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String name = field.getName();
    Object value = field.get(abc);
    System.out.printf("Field name: %s, Field value: %s%n", name, value);
}
```

#### See also:

- [Reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: Bear  in mind that this excludes inherited fields!

Comment: instead of `getDeclaredFields()`, use `getAllFields()` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2405757/755804

Comment: Best answer  ever !!!

Answer (score 6):

You can also install the jython - a Python itnerpreter on the JVM, and use the builtin Python "dir" function.

It is great because it allows you to interact live with your objects:

```
[gwidion@powerpuff]$ jython
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.6.0_13
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import java.awt
>>> dir(java.awt.Window)
['active', 'addPropertyChangeListener', 'addWindowFocusListener', 'addWindowListener',
'addWindowStateListener', 'alwaysOnTop', 'alwaysOnTopSupported', 'applyResourceBundle', 
'bufferStrategy', 'createBufferStrategy',...
```