# Java reflection field value in extends class

Tags: java, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access to private inherited fields via reflection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567372/access-to-private-inherited-fields-via-reflection-in-java)

Hello i hava got problem with init value with java reflection.

i have got simple class

```
 public class A extends B {
     private String name;
 }

  public class B {
     private String superName;   
  }
```

and also i have got simple function:

```
   public void createRandom(Class<T> clazz , List<String> classFields){


    try {
        T object = clazz.newInstance();
        for(String s : classFields){
            clazz.getDeclaredField(s);
        }

    } catch(Exception e){

    }

   }
```

My function do other stuff but i have got problem because i have got error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: superName
```

How can i set all class field also field from super Class  using reflection ??

I have got all class fields (also inherited) and i am using function `field.set(Object obj, Object value)` but in this way i can not set inherited class fields :/

I havent got problem to get all class field i am using Spring ReflectionUtils.doWithfield. 
i stored all field names in `List<String> classField`, so i known all clazz fields also inherited. But my problem is how to set values into all clazz fields.

Comment: How are you invoking `createRandom()`? what are the values of `clazz` and the list?

Answer (score 8):

If I had to guess, I'm assuming you are calling this method on class A, and expecting to be able to view the underlying fields declared in class B, like so:

```
A.class.getDeclaredField("superName");
```

This is not the case, and will throw an Exception (`java.lang.NoSuchFieldException`). Reflection does not check super classes to find fields or methods. So since class `A` doesn't define `superName`, it will not be found using reflection like that. However, you could modify your code to make it check all superclasses until it reaches `null` as the superclass, at which point if it's still not found, it definately doesn't exist.

Here's an example:

```
public static Field findUnderlying(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName) {
    Class<?> current = clazz;
    do {
       try {
           return current.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
       } catch(Exception e) {}
    } while((current = current.getSuperclass()) != null);
    return null;
}
```

Here's an example call: `findUnderlying(A.class, "superName")`; it would first check class A for the field. Since A doesn't have it, the dowhile then moves on to it's superclass, which is B (not null so continue). B does have it, so it then returns the field. If B didn't have it, it would then check Object, then return null since Object doesn't have a superclass.

Comment: +1 for the method but you should never reassign a method parameter (`clazz` in that case).

Comment: @aymeric Yeah, thanks, actually had it the way I edited it to now before, but changed it, wasn't thinking about it :)

Comment: But i know how to get all class field (also inherited) . But my problem is how to set all field values ? i found only one method to do this : field.set(Object obj, Object value), but this method can not allowed set inherited fields :/

Comment: @Lukasz Wozniczka If you call `someFieldOfSuperClass.set(subClassOfClassWithField, value)` it will still work

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(s);
```

instead of (or in addition with some try-catch):

```
clazz.getDeclaredField(s);
```

**EDIT:**

To set the value for the superclass, use the following:

```
Field f = clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(s);
f.setAccessible(true); // Especially necessary if the field is not public
f.set(yourObject, theValue);
```

Comment: Yea i know that . But how can i set value into inherited class field ??

Answer (score 1):

get super class using [Class.getSuperclass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29). Then using super class, you can get it's fields.

Answer (score -1):

It wont work with instance of A even if A extends from B , it is because private members are not accessible in sub classes . try changing the access of superName to protected and if it works ...

Comment: I don't think changing visibility in class definition is solution, OP is looking for way how to access private fields

Comment: No changing visibility allow you save value into field with private modifier.