# Why reflection does not provide method to query all fields in inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: java, reflection

I was trying to find a `private` field using reflection with a given name, which may also reside in parent class or somewhere else in the inheritance hierarchy.

But I found out that there is no such method in `Class` which provides this information.

`Class#getDeclaredFields()` - provides all fields `private`, `public` but *does not* include inheritance hierarchy

`Class#getFields()` - includes inheritance hierarchy but searches only `public` fields.

So why is there no method that provides both types of information?

I know this can easily be implemented and there are libraries that provide this, but still can  be included in java itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a child `class` is not aware of any `private` fields in a parent `class` - it does not inherit them.

The problem at hand can be solved very easily by walking up the class hierarchy with `getSuperClass`

```
public static Field getField(final Class<?> toReflectOn, final String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    try {
        return toReflectOn.getField(fieldName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        if (toReflectOn.getSuperclass() != null) {
            return getField(toReflectOn.getSuperclass(), fieldName);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567372/access-to-private-inherited-fields-via-reflection-in-java) other SO post provides a more sophisticated approach that loops over all fields in the class hierarchy.