# Java Reflection - how to set value for the class which are extended from One and Two

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, javabeans

**Goal :**

set the value for a class fields as well the extended class fields

**Example :**

```
public class CreateRequisitionRO extends AbstractPortfolioSpecificRO {....}
```

i am able to set value for the `CreateRequisitionRO` but not able to set value for `AbstractPortfolioSpecificRO` which is being extended.

This is how i set the value :

```
public Object creatObjectWithDefaultValue(String className) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class<?> objectClass = null;
        Object clsObject =null;
        try {
            objectClass = Class.forName(className);
            clsObject = objectClass.newInstance();
             Field[] fields = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();
             for(Field f:fields){
                  if(!f.isAccessible()){
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        Class<?> type = f.getType();
                        if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(Integer.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject, DefaultParamValuesEnum.INTEGER.getDefaultInt());  
                        } else if( !Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(java.math.BigDecimal.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject, DefaultParamValuesEnum.BIGDECIMAL.getDdefaultBigDecimal());  
                        } else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(org.joda.time.LocalDate.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject,DefaultParamValuesEnum.DATE.getDefaultDate());  
                        }  else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(boolean.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject, DefaultParamValuesEnum.BOOLEAN.getDefaultBoolean());  
                        } else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(java.lang.String.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject, DefaultParamValuesEnum.STRING.getDefaultString());  
                        }
                        else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(long.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject,DefaultParamValuesEnum.LONGVALUE.getDefaultLong());  
                        }
                     }
               }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return clsObject;
    }
```

This is how i call the above method :

```
classObject.creatJSONObject("com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO");
```

The above way sets value for all the fields available in `CreateRequisitionRO` not fields which are available in extended class.

How to set it?

Comment: you should wrap this check around the other checks: `if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()))` instead of doing the same check over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clazz.getSuperclass()` to retrieve the supertype of `CreateRequisitionRO`.  Once you have a handle on the supertype `AbstractPortfolioSpecificRO` you can iterate its fields.  I would recommend storing all of these fields in a `List<Field>`.  Iterate through this list and set the fields based upon your conditional logic.

I have provided a quick example of how to perform this.  In my example, `Child` extends `Parent`.  The recursive `getFields` method returns a `List<Field>` that contains all of the fields for `Child`.  I then iterate through the `List<Field>` setting the value for each one.  Notice that I must switch the accessibility of private fields.

**Child.Java**

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public String a;
    public String b;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Child child = new Child();
        List<Field> fields = getFields(child.getClass());

        for(Field f: fields){
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(child, "Test");
        }

        for(Field fd: fields){
            System.out.println(fd.get(child));
            fd.setAccessible(false);
        }


    }

    public static List<Field> getFields(Class<?> clazz){
        List<Field> list = new ArrayList<Field>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredFields()));

        if(clazz.getSuperclass() != null){
            list.addAll(getFields(clazz.getSuperclass()));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Parent.java**

```
public class Parent {
    private String x;
    public String y;
    protected String z;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation +1. will do this and mark this as answer as this will help others too.

Comment: @Anto Glad I could help.  If you have any further questions let me know.

Comment: Kevin i get only field name like the following `userId` when i use `getSuperclass().` but i need to get like `private java.lang.String com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO.custodianN` is it possible

Comment: `getDeclaredFields` should pull the private fields also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29183/discussion-between-anto-and-kevin-bowersox)

Answer (score 1):

You can get super class of your class using `Class<SuperClass> superClazz = clazz.getSuperclass();`

Once got, get the `Field[]` using `superClazz.getFields()` and use `set` method of `Field`

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSuperclass()` method to obtain the class object of superclass. and then in the similar way get the fields of superclass.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
```

you can use above function for achieving same ..

also check [Access to private inherited fields via reflection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567372/access-to-private-inherited-fields-via-reflection-in-java)