# Detecting existence of Touch Listeners

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I want to find out if some items (Buttons, EditText etc) has Touch Listeners - and only if there aren't so I want to add my own Listeners (I get the items from another class).
Is there a way to detect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Niko i was able to do what i want.
On api >= 15 , i used reflection (using Niko example) to get the field: mListenerInfo, then i used reflection again to get the field mOnTouchListener. now if it's null it means there is no touch listener, otherwise it has.
this is a code example (without try catch):

```
Field field_mListenerInfo = null;
Object originalListener = null;
Object myListenerInfo = null;
Field field_mOnTouchListener = null;

View viewForField = new View(activity); //needed just to get field name
field_mListenerInfo = viewForField.getClass().getDeclaredField("mListenerInfo");
field_mListenerInfo.setAccessible(true);
originalListener = field_mOnTouchListener.get(myListenerInfo );
myListenerInfo = field_mListenerInfo.get(view);
field_mOnTouchListener = myListenerInfo.getClass().getDeclaredField("mOnTouchListener");
field_mOnTouchListener.setAccessible(true);
```

now if originalListener is null it means there is no touchListner. else, you can actually use this Listener - for example to concat few listeners.
If there are no Listeners at all so  mListenerInfo will be null. 
of course you should pack this code with try catch, otherwise it will break if any of your fields is null.

Answer (score 1):

You can get private field of `View` called `mOnTouchListener`

Here is how you use reflection: [Access to private inherited fields via reflection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567372/access-to-private-inherited-fields-via-reflection-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the Quick respond! It sounds like a great idea but i can't find this field mOnTouchListener you are talking about. All i see is some field called mListenerInfo but i can't understand what to do with it

Comment: Here you can see classes for different API levels http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/View.java/ In the latest SDK there seems to be method getListenerInfo() which has this private field mOnTouchListener. For multi API level support you will have to use different approaches to access the field.

Comment: thanks! i still got a lot of work to do but now i'm on the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that checking the documentation would be your best bet.

Comment: I did. couldn't find anything useful

Answer (score 0):

After a while of searching for solutions for this problem myself, I've found a solution that works.
I hope the attached code helps:

```
private static View.OnTouchListener getOnTouchListener(View view) {
        View.OnTouchListener retrievedListener = null;
        String viewStr = "android.view.View";
        String lInfoStr = "android.view.View$ListenerInfo";
        try {

            Field listenerField = Class.forName(viewStr).getDeclaredField("mListenerInfo");
            Object listenerInfo = null;

            if (listenerField != null) {
                listenerField.setAccessible(true);
                listenerInfo = listenerField.get(view);
            }

            Field clickListenerField = Class.forName(lInfoStr).getDeclaredField("mOnTouchListener");

            if (clickListenerField != null && listenerInfo != null) {
                clickListenerField.setAccessible(true);
                retrievedListener = (View.OnTouchListener) clickListenerField.get(listenerInfo);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Timber.e("getOnTouchListener() No Such Field. %s",ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Timber.e("getOnTouchListener() Illegal Access. %s",ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Timber.e("getOnTouchListener() Class Not Found. %s",ex.getMessage());
        }

        return retrievedListener;
    }
```