# Set private field value with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have 2 classes: `Father` and `Child`

```
public class Father implements Serializable, JSONInterface {

    private String a_field;

    //setter and getter here

}

public class Child extends Father {
    //empty class
}
```

With reflection I want to set `a_field` in `Child` class:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Child");
Object cc = clazz.newInstance();

Field f1 = cc.getClass().getField("a_field");
f1.set(cc, "reflecting on life");
String str1 = (String) f1.get(cc.getClass());
System.out.println("field: " + str1);
```

but I have an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: a_field

But if I try:

```
Child child = new Child();
child.setA_field("123");
```

it works.

Using setter method I have same problem:

```
method = cc.getClass().getMethod("setA_field");
method.invoke(cc, new Object[] { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" });
```

Comment: You need to get the superclass of the Class first, before beeing able to acces the field. [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567372/access-to-private-inherited-fields-via-reflection-in-java)

Comment: The field is not part of the Child class Since it is private, it is not even visible in the Child class.The setters are public and are inherited, which means they can be called as if they were declared in the Child class.

Comment: Instead of retrieving the field which is private,set its value by retrieving its setter Method

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution. Now I can try

Answer (score 186, accepted):

To access a private field you need to set `Field::setAccessible` to true. You can pull the field off the super class. This code works:

```
Class<?> clazz = Child.class;
Object cc = clazz.newInstance();

Field f1 = cc.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("a_field");
f1.setAccessible(true);
f1.set(cc, "reflecting on life");
String str1 = (String) f1.get(cc);
System.out.println("field: " + str1);
```

Answer (score 140):

Using [`FieldUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html) from the *Apache Commons Lang 3*:

```
FieldUtils.writeField(childInstance, "a_field", "Hello", true);
```

The `true` forces it to set, even if the field is *private*.

Comment: Thank goodness for this escape hatch from those idiotic fields that MUST be set by Spring Bean dependency injection.

Comment: Try it in RuntimeException on field "cause" - it's doesn't working. On Jdk11+

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

Answer (score 19):

**Kotlin verison**

Get private variable using below extension functions

```
fun <T : Any> T.getPrivateProperty(variableName: String): Any? {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField(variableName).let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this)
    }
}
```

Set private variable value get the variable

```
fun <T : Any> T.setAndReturnPrivateProperty(variableName: String, data: Any): Any? {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField(variableName).let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(this, data)
        return@let field.get(this)
    }
}
```

Get variable use:

```
val bool = <your_class_object>.getPrivateProperty("your_variable") as String
```

Set and get variable use:

```
val bool = <your_class_object>.setAndReturnPrivateProperty("your_variable", true) as Boolean
val str = <your_class_object>.setAndReturnPrivateProperty("your_variable", "Hello") as String
```

---

**Java version**

```
public class RefUtil {

    public static Field setFieldValue(Object object, String fieldName, Object valueTobeSet) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = getField(object.getClass(), fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(object, valueTobeSet);
        return field;
    }

    public static Object getPrivateFieldValue(Object object, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = getField(object.getClass(), fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(object);
    }

    private static Field getField(Class mClass, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        try {
            return mClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Class superClass = mClass.getSuperclass();
            if (superClass == null) {
                throw e;
            } else {
                return getField(superClass, fieldName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Set private value use

```
RefUtil.setFieldValue(<your_class_object>, "your_variableName", newValue);
```

Get private value use

```
Object value = RefUtil.getPrivateFieldValue(<your_class_object>, "your_variableName");
```

Comment: Very nice answer. General, without dependencies, I love it.

Answer (score 7):

This one can access private fields as well without having to do anything

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
Object value = FieldUtils.readField(entity, fieldName, true);
```

Answer (score -5):

As per the Javadoc of [`Class.getField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a Field object that reflects the specified **public member field** of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

This method only returns public fields. Since `a_field` is private, it won't be found.

Here's a working code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Child");
        Object cc = clazz.newInstance();

        Field f1 = cc.getClass().getField("a_field");
        f1.set(cc, "reflecting on life");
        String str1 = (String) f1.get(cc);
        System.out.println("field: " + str1);
    }

}

class Father implements Serializable {
    public String a_field;
}

class Child extends Father {
//empty class
}
```

Note that I also changed your line `String str1 = (String) f1.get(cc.getClass());` to `String str1 = (String) f1.get(cc);` because you need to give the object of the field, not the class.

---

If you want to keep your field private, then you need to retrieve the getter / setter method and invoke those instead. The code you have given does not work because, to get a method, you also need to specify it's arguments, so

```
cc.getClass().getMethod("setA_field");
```

must be

```
cc.getClass().getMethod("setA_field", String.class);
```

Here's a working code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Child");
        Object cc = clazz.newInstance();
        cc.getClass().getMethod("setA_field", String.class).invoke(cc, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        String str1 = (String) cc.getClass().getMethod("getA_field").invoke(cc);
        System.out.println("field: " + str1);
    }

}

class Father implements Serializable {

    private String a_field;

    public String getA_field() {
        return a_field;
    }

    public void setA_field(String a_field) {
        this.a_field = a_field;
    }

}

class Child extends Father {
    //empty class
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but a_field must be private. Alternativelly can I call setter method?