# PowerMockito Mocked final class gson.fromJson() Returns null

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have this code in main class  -

```
try {
    extraPlayer = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, ExtraPlayer.class);// this returns null
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Here **extraPlayer is coming as null**
I have mocked @Mock Gson gsonMock;

Here **ExtraPlayer** is a static class.

I have written this test code  -

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String jsonResponse = "{\"status\":\"waiting\",\"no\":\"12\"}";
    when(playerHandlerMock.resetPlayer("someString", "someString", "1",true    
         )).thenReturn(jsonResponse);       
    Gson gsonMock = PowerMockito.mock(Gson.class);
    ExtraPlayer extraPlayer = new ExtraPlayer();
    extraPlayer.setNo("12");
    extraPlayer.setStatus("Waiting");

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ResetModemResponse.class); // using this for static class but didn't work.

    PowerMockito.when(gsonMock.fromJson(jsonResponse, ExtraPlayer.class)).thenReturn(extraPlayer);

    playerMock.performWaiting();
}
```

**ExtraPlayer.java**

```
public static class ExtraPlayer{

    String no;
    String status;      

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getNo() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

}
```

I have added these annotations to the test class -

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Gson.class)
```

**why extraPlayer is null ? please help/Suggest.**

Comment: how do you inject gson object into the class under test?

Comment: gson is Autowired in main class. in test i am using  like this -
 when(gsonMock.fromJson(jsonResponse, ExtraPlayer.class)).thenReturn(extraPlayer);

Comment: is `fromJson` a static method?

Comment: no, Gson.java is final class. pkg is - import com.google.gson.Gson;

Comment: @jaythakur did you found the solution for above

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use the standard `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotation with mockito, then yes, the framework would take care of the injection of the mock into the class under test (regardless of the existence of the setters etc.).

Another thing is the `playerMock`, which i assume is the class under test.

Do not mock the class under test, create a normal instance and then inject the dependencies... the `performWaiting` method does not seem to accept the response String, so you would have to inject that also somehow (unless you left some parts out):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // Arrange
    String jsonResponse = "{\"status\":\"waiting\",\"no\":\"12\"}";     
    Gson gsonMock = PowerMockito.mock(Gson.class);
    ExtraPlayer extraPlayer = new ExtraPlayer();
    extraPlayer.setNo("12");
    extraPlayer.setStatus("Waiting");

    PowerMockito.when(gsonMock.fromJson(jsonResponse, ExtraPlayer.class)).thenReturn(extraPlayer);

    Player player = new Player();
    player.setGson(gsonMock);
    player.setResponse(jsonResponse);

    // Act
    player.performWaiting();

    // Assert ...
}
```

Comment: Gson.java is a final class. I was using {@Mock}, {@InjectMock}. but it was throwing error that mockito can't handle final.

Comment: yes.. thats why u need powermock and inject manually that dependency

Comment: can't do {player.setGson(gsonMock);} as setGson is not a method.

Comment: You need to create one.. a package level one will be sufficient

Comment: Not really.. if you cant inject by constructor or a setter and you are using powermock, then you are left with manual injection by reflection.

Comment: by "manual injection by reflection" , do you mean {@Autowired} {@Mock} {@InjectMock} ?

Comment: Nope, i meant the raw java reflection api.

Comment: ohk. I used { @Mock Gson gsonMock;} now gson is not null. but explayer is null here - extraPlayer = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, ExtraPlayer.class);

Comment: any suggestion nw ? one thing - ExtraPlayer.class is a static class.

Comment: do you pass `jsonResponse` into the method?

Comment: passing json like this - when(gsonMock.fromJson(jsonResponse, ExtraPlayer.class)).thenReturn(extraPlayer);

Comment: this is a set-up.. When you invoke player.performWaiting();.. it does not accept the response, so how do you expect to have it passed to the gson call?

Comment: Sry, it is like this - when(playerHandlerMock.resetPlayer("someString", "someString", "1", true)).thenReturn(jsonResponse);

Comment: debugged , jsonResponse is coming fine there. it seems somewhere problem with ExtraPlayer static class. need to mock in test class ? if y, hw ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a static class.. there can be methods or fields. Try to add all the code related to the case.. i have a feeling you did not post everything. Otherwise the analysis does not make sense

Comment: ExtraPlayer is a simple POJO class inside the main class.

Comment: shouldnt matter.. is the String exaclty the same as in the set-up?

Comment: there are some more setters & getters. thats it.

Comment: can you please suggest, how to do this with reflection ?

Comment: just try one of the answers on stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716952/set-private-field-value-with-reflection