# Listening multiple directories for file creation in Java

Tags: java, file, jvm, nio

I'm using inotify nio wrappers to catch file creation in a specific directory. Okay, I have this

```
private final String tmpDir1 = Files.createTempDirectory(null);
private final String tmpDir2 = Files.createTempDirectory(null);

WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault.newWatchService()

Paths.get(tmpDir1).register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE)
Paths.get(tmpDir2).register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE)

public String getModifiedFilePath(){
    WatchKey key = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchService.take())
    //Does p belongs to tmpDir1 or tmpDir2?
    Path p = ((WatchEvent<Path>)(key.pollEvents().iterator().next())).context()
    return //???
}
```

As specified in the documentation of the method `WatchEvent#context`

> Returns the context for the event. In the case of `ENTRY_CREATE`,
>   `ENTRY_DELETE`, and `ENTRY_MODIFY` events the context is a `Path` that is
>   the ***relative path between the directory registered with the watch***
>   ***service, and the entry that is created, deleted, or modified***.

But `sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchKey` contains the field `private final Path dir`. But the class is package private. Is there a way to get the directory name the file returned by the `WatchEvent#context` belongs to?

UPD: Creating inotify instance for each directory I want to watch sounds really wierd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enjoy

```
public Path getModifiedFilePath() throws InterruptedException {
    WatchKey key = watchService.take();
    return (Path) key.watchable();
}
```

Comment: Cooool. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

By using the Java Reflection API you can modify the access modifiers.
[Set private field value with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716952/set-private-field-value-with-reflection)