# How to iterate on scala class members for found null value

Tags: scala

I need to check if all value is null in a Scala class (Test.class) defined as:

```
class Test extends Serializable {
  a: String = _
  b: String = _
  c: String = _
}
```

I can't change this class (is legacy code in my project).
How can i do this without a lot of if? The real class have 22 fields.

I've tried to use java reflection to detect the defined fields, but they are all defined every and I can't access it because the fields are private for the reflectors. (`criteria.getClass.getDeclaredFields`)

Comment: `field.setAccessible(true)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716952/set-private-field-value-with-reflection

Comment: thanks, I've changed the question with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Dmytro Mitin , it works for me. I think that I will use this approach for check the not null element:

```
testClass.getClass.getDeclaredFields.flatMap(f => {
        f.setAccessible(true)
        Option(f.get(criteria))
    }).length
```