# Access private inner class with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Let's take the following class with a static inner class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Request {
    private String contactUrl;
    private Resources resources;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private static class Resources {
        private String basketId;
        private String customerId;
    }
}
```

I need to access the `basketId` from another class like this:

```
Request request = new Request();
request.getResources.setBasketId("5");
```

This won't compile unless I define the `Resources` class as `public`.

Is there any other way using Lombok accessing this field while keeping `Resources` private?

Comment: What’s the problem with making the inner class public? If it’s returned from the getter, users already know it exists and what methods it has. What are you trying to achieve by making it private?

Comment: Non-static inner class objects require an object of the enclosing class, while nested (static) class objects do not. This is one valid reason, altho I don't say it is the OP's reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@Delegate` to effectively 'copy' every method that your private inner class has to the outer (and the implementation just calls that method on the inner):

```
@Delegate private Resources resources;
```

Note that having a type used in a signature (the constructors, fields, methods, etc – the non-code aspects of a type) such that the type is less visible than the signature, is **really weird**: Here you have a public method that returns an effectively invisible type (Resources) to all code that isn't in this very file. This is a bad idea; nobody can usefull call this method. Either get rid of the getter and setter (For example, by using Delegate instead), or make the Resources inner class public.

Let's take a step back: What are you trying to accomplish? For example, if you don't want anybody to use that inner Resources class without the outer's knowledge, that's easily doable: Just make a private constructor in Resources, and, voila. Now nobody can make instances except your outer.

Answer (score 1):

To keep `Resources` private, you can delegate the setter method e.g.:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Request {
    private String contactUrl;
    private Resources resources;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private static class Resources {
        private String basketId;
        private String customerId;
    }

    public setBasketId(String id) {
        resources.setBasketId(id)
    }
}
```

Or you can use reflection: [Set private field value with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716952/set-private-field-value-with-reflection)

Comment: When speaking about delegate, you could probably use `@lombok.Delegate private Resources resources`. But I'm unsure whether exposing the inner class details this way is any better than exposing the class itself.