# MapReduce - Mock with Mokito

Tags: mapreduce, mockito, powermock

I have the a reducer class that I wanted to write test cases:

## Reduce class:

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(MyReducer.class);
    public static List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String id = null;
    private MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text> mos;

    @Override
    public void setup(final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text>(context);

         final Path[] uris = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());

        try {
            final BufferedReader readBuffer1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(uris[0].toString()));
            String line;
            while ((line = readBuffer1.readLine()) != null) {
                l1.add(line);
            }
            readBuffer1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }

    public void reduce(final Text key, final Iterable<Text> values, final Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        final String[] key1 = key.toString().split("-");
        final String keyA = key1[10];
        final String date = key1[1];

/* Some condition check */ 

           mos.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(inputEventValue), keyA + "//date=" +
                    date.substring(0, 4) + "-" + date.substring(4, 6));

       }

    @Override
    public void cleanup(final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos.close();
    }

}
```

## Test Case looks like :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

   @Mock
    private MyReducer.Context mockContext;

    MyReducer reducer;
    MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text> mos;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        reducer = new MyReducer();
    }


   @Test
    public void myReducerTest() throws Exception {

        MyReducer spy = PowerMockito.spy(new MyReducer());
        doNothing().when(spy).setup(mockContext);

        mos = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text>(mockContext);
        List<Text> sline = new ArrayList<>() ;
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        l1.add(“1234”);
        sline.add(new Text(“xyz”));
        Whitebox.setInternalState(MyReducer.class,”l1", l1);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(MyReducer.class,"mos",mos);
        reducer.reduce(new Text(“xyz-20200101-1234),sline,mockContext);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        /*
         * this will do the clean up part
         */
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockContext);
    }
```

When running in Debug mode it goes to the reducer's reduce method and fails with NullPointerException where mos write statement is?

## Complete Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.getNamedOutputsList(MultipleOutputs.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.<init>(MultipleOutputs.java:324)
    at MyTest.myeducerTest
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
```

Mocking mos errors as mos is not a static.

Any suggestion.

```
Junit - ReduceDriver, withInput, withOutput,testRun  doesn't work.
```

Thanks.

I tried mocking Multiple outputs as suggested:

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

@Mock
    private MyReducer.Context mockContext;

```
    List<String> namedOut = new ArrayList<>();
    namedOut.add("NM1");
    namedOut.add("NM2");
```

MultipleOutputs spy = PowerMockito.spy(new MultipleOutputs<>(mockContext));
when(spy, "getNamedOutputsList(mockContext)").thenReturn(namedOut);

But this gives me error : org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: no method found with name 'getNamedOutputsList(() anyObject())' with parameter types : [] in class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.

Comment: Your (incomplete) stacktrace does not really indicate that it fails from the line `mos.write`, so I didn't consider that in my answer. You might want to add the complete stacktrace if it does not fail during the construction of `MultipleOutputs`.

Comment: updated the complete stacktrace

Comment: `MultipleOutputs.<init>` confirms that it is the constructor. Did you give what I wrote in my answer a try?

Comment: I don't know how to use reflection to mock mos @second

Comment: I still think its `cleaner` to just mock the configuration object. I didn't test that, so in case it does not work for you I added a link for the reflection stuff.

Comment: I did mocking config but that didn't work. See the code above that I tried mocking/spy on MultiplleOutputs for getNamedOutputs method which is private static. Any suggestion pls

Comment: You used the wrong syntax for mocking static methods. You have to declare a `mockStatic` for the class and then use the `MultipleOutputs.getNamedOutputsList(...)` inside the `when`. You do not need a `spy` for this part.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not define what `mockContext.getContext()` should return for your test, so it returns `null` and fails.

Based on [this sourcecode](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) the methods looks like this (so you might use a different version):

```java
private static List<String> getNamedOutputsList(JobContext job) {
   List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
     job.getConfiguration().get(MULTIPLE_OUTPUTS, ""), " ");
   while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     names.add(st.nextToken());
   }
   return names;
}
```

`JobContext` seems to refer to your mock `Reducer.Context mockContext`, so you need to define the appropriate behaviour so that it returns what it is supposed to return.

Note that this call originates from the constructor of `MultipleOutputs`.

Also take note of the static `getCountersEnabled` method that is invoked from the constructor and interacts with the context.

---

> Mocking mos errors as mos is not a static.

You could probably use reflections to put a mocked version of `mos` into your `MyReducer` class.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32717284) for some example on how to mock a private static field.

---

Edit:

If you try to mock the conig do it like this:

```
Configuration config = Mockito.mock(Configuration.class);
when(mockContext.getConfiguration()).thenReturn(config);
```

As far as I see the `get` that are invoked on the configuration object always provide a default value, so it shouldn't matter if the key/value pair is in there or not.

Comment: This is what I have tried so far, but no luck. Suggestion from here:

Comment: @PrepareForTest({MultipleOutputs.class, MyReducer.class}) List<String> namedOut = new ArrayList<>(); namedOut.add("NM1"); namedOut.add("NM2");MultipleOutputs spy = PowerMockito.spy(new MultipleOutputs<>(mockContext));
        PowerMockito.doReturn(namedOut).when(spy, MultipleOutputs.class,"getNamedOutputsList",any(JobContext.class));

Comment: This erros with InvokationTargetException. It goes into the MultipleOutputs getNamedOutputsList method

Comment: What needs to be done to define the behaviour of mockContext ?

Comment: I have added a simple example on how the config class should be mocked. You might need to search for the correct `Configuration` class.