# How to mock a global object in a class properly?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Let say I have a class like so

```
Class A{
   private K Obj = (K)(AppContext.getSpringContext().getBean("obj"))
   
  public void method1{
     // uses Obj
  }

  public void method2{
    // uses Obj
  }

}
```

And I need to write junits for method1 and method2 by changing the behavior of Obj in method 1 and method 2. In my junit class I am setting the appcontext as so:

```
public class AccountInformationManagerTest {

    private CCBSAppContext appContext;

    @Mock
    ApplicationContext springContext;
     
    @Mock
    Object obj;

   @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        appContext = new CCBSAppContext();
        appContext.setApplicationContext(springContext);
        Mockito.when(springContext.getBean("obj")).thenReturn(obj);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am setting globally the appcontext. I don't want mock the static calls as I am using jacoco and powermockito doesn't integrate very well with jacoco. The problem here is that appcontext is now a global object which is shared across all methods and I need to modify the behavior of obj as I test the two methods. This will create a concurrency issue. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the concurrency issue.

Answer (score 1):

TBH avoid `(K)(AppContext.getSpringContext().getBean("obj"))` directly inject dependency or autowire the dependency . Then in its easily testable and add obj to the class via SpringTestUtils or setters.

```
@Autowired
K obj;
```

Else you can mock springContext getBean method for every test

```
@Test
void fun {
     Mockito.when(springContext.getBean(Mockito.eq("obj"))).thenReturn(obj);
     // doSomething
}


@Test
void fun2 {
     Mockito.when(springContext.getBean(Mockito.eq("obj"))).thenReturn(obj2);
     // doSomething2
}
```

Comment: I can't. My manager told me I can't change the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection to set the `Obj`.  Then you can set `Obj` to be a mocked object.

[Here is a SO answer describing how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32717284/1490322)