# Inject spring beans into a non-managed class

Tags: java, spring

I have this non-managed class that I want to inject spring beans (that I don't known a-priory what they are). How can I do that?

For example, let's say I have the following class:

```java
public class NonManagedClass extends APIClass {

  @Resource
  private Service1 service;

  @Resource
  private Service2 service2;

  // here i can declare many different dependencies

  @Resource
  private ServiceN serviceN;

  @Override
  public void executeBusinessStuffs() {
    // business logics
  }

}
```

I need in someway to let spring inject these dependencies in my class. I have access to these objects after created, so it's easy to me call any method that can accomplish this functionality. For example:

```java
@Service
public void SomeAPIService {

  @Resource
  private BeanInjector beanInjector; // I'm looking for some funcionality of spring like this

  public void someProcessingFunction(Class<? extends APIClass> clazz) throws Exception {
    APIClass instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
    beanInjector.injectBeans(instance);
    instance.executeBusinessStuffs();
  }

}
```

Does Spring have such functionality to inject beans based on fields annotation for a non-managed class?

Comment: I dont think spring will provide this feature for any reason.. it will make the overall framework a big mess. However, you can use reflection to make this possible

Comment: If you still insist to make this work, refer this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716952/set-private-field-value-with-reflection

Comment: Inject the `ApplicationContext` and use `getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(instance);`. Or let Spring do it all and use `getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(clazz);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `BeanInjector` with `ApplicationContext` and you are almost there. From there you can get the [`AutowireCapableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) which provides some handy methods like [`createBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#createBean-java.lang.Class-int-boolean-) and [`autowireBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBean-java.lang.Object-).

```java
@Service
public void SomeAPIService {

  @Resource
  private ApplicationContext ctx;

  public void someProcessingFunction(Class<? extends APIClass> clazz) throws Exception {
    APIClass instance = ctx.createBean(clazz);
    instance.executeBusinessStuffs();
  }
}
```

or if you really like to construct stuff yourself instead of using the container:

```java
@Service
public void SomeAPIService {

  @Resource
  private ApplicationContext ctx;

  public void someProcessingFunction(Class<? extends APIClass> clazz) throws Exception {
    APIClass instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(instance);
    instance.executeBusinessStuffs();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm.. good point. Do you know if using this `autowireBean` create any records in spring's data-structures? I don't wanna to create information there, I just want to wire the dependencies in this loose instance. I'm asking this because I've seen this another methods there, like `autowireBeanProperties` from `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by **reate any records in spring's data-structures**? What has Spring Data and records to do with autowiring?

Comment: I mean, I don't wanna spring to keep track of my non-managed beans in case someone decicdes to ask them to be autowired (e.g.: `@Autowire NonManagedClass`)

Comment: Why would it? It isn't registering anything it is only auto wiring the bean itself. If you want to make it part of the context you would need to do `registerBean`.