# Setting up different Java class fields value by a single value on some counter value

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Setting up different Java class fields value by a single value on some counter value?

In a Java class, having similar kind of fields like:

```
public class User {
    private String user_Id_1;
    private String user_Id_2;
    private String user_Id_3;
    private String user_Id_4;
    ...
    
    public void setUserId(int num, String user_Id) {
        switch (num) {
            case 1: setUser_Id_1(user_Id); break;
            case 2: setUser_Id_2(user_Id); break;
            case 3: setUser_Id_3(user_Id); break;
            case 4: setUser_Id_4(user_Id); break;
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

---

The requirement is - The ***User class field names resemble the exact field names in generated editable PDF Form*** like **user_Id_1**, **user_Id_2** etc. For the 1st user record, the form field '**user_Id_1**' must be set with value of "user_Id" (*"user_Id" -> this value maps to the database field value*), For the 2nd user record, the form field 'user_Id_2' must be set with same value of "user_Id", and so on.

> How to reduce the multiple switch-case/if statements?

Comment: why not use a map, and use num as the key value? not a single if-statement or switch needed

Comment: @Stultuske The requirement is totally different from what you are suggesting. can you show me a show-case, may be I not getting you.

Comment: in that case, how do you think a one on one mapping can be reduced?

Comment: I am also sure that, such conditions can't be reduced, just checking with you all - if my assumptions is correct or not.

Comment: That’s a nonsensical requirement. Why do the **private** field names have to match the PDF form when the parameters of the public method to set them do not?

Comment: You already asked a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220694/how-to-set-different-fields-value-in-java-based-on-some-condition no ?

Comment: Thinking about Stultuske's comment, maybe you could have a map of int to method reference: `Map.of(1, User::setUser_Id_1, 2, User::setUser_Id_2, ...)` and call it thus: `map.get(num).call(user_Id)`.

Comment: But in any case, if you use the new Java [enhanced switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/switch-expressions.html), your existing code will be much shorter and clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: use reflection iterating the fields

```
for( Field field : User.class.getDeclaredFields() ){
  // explore if necessary e.g.
  if( field.getName().startsWith( "yourCriteria" )
      && field.getType().equals( String.class ) ){
     boolean restoreAccessible = field.canAccess( this );
     field.setAccessible( true );
     field.set( this, field.getName() );
     field.setAccessible( restoreAccessible );
  }
}
```

You need the accessible-shenanigans to surcome private and protected access. It might even work if the code is part of the User-class - I did not check the indirection via the Field object there. If the code is not part of your User you need to replace field.canAccess( this ) by field.canAccess( yourInstance );

see also [Set private field value with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716952/set-private-field-value-with-reflection)

Comment: Another hint: If you have a class-hierarchy you have to take care of the inherited fields manually since getDeclaredFields only returns the Fields defined in the particular class, not the union of Fields across the complete class/interface-hierarchy

Comment: …now we only need some way to convert the logic expressed with `switch` in the original code to something expressible in the form of “`.getName().startsWith( "yourCriteria" )`”. There is, by the way, no point in restoring the accessible flag after the operation. There is no other reference to this `Field` object and it will be subject to garbage collection. Further, a `Class` object is only equal to itself, so you can use `==` instead of calling `equals`.