# Access fields of a TestNG test class from a TestListenerAdapter

Tags: reflection, testng

**Background**

I have the following situation:

- My test-classes implement `org.testng.ITest`
- They all have a `Helper` containing info on the current test environment (e.g. device-under-test)

For example:

```
com.company.appundertest.Helper h;

public class TestClass implements org.testng.ITest {
    private String testName;

    //Helper is initialized externally in Factory + DataProvider 
    //and passed to Constructor.
    public TestClass(com.company.appundertest.Helper hh) {

    this.h = hh;

    //constructor sets the test-name dynamically
    //to distinguish multiple parallel test runs.
    this.testName = "some dynamic test name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return this.testName;
    }

    @Test
    public void failingTest() {
        //test that fails...
    }
}
```

- These test-classes are executed in parallel using Factory and parallel data-provider.
- Upon Test Failure, I need to access variables *within the Helper instance of the failing test-class*. These will be used to identify the environment at the point of failure (e.g. take screenshot on failing device).

This problem essentially boils down to:

**How would I access fields within the TestNG test-class?**

**References**

- [Access to private inherited fields via reflection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567372/access-to-private-inherited-fields-via-reflection-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example method. You can insert this in a Test Listener class (which extends `TestListenerAdapter`)

```
public class CustomTestNGListener extends TestListenerAdapter{

//accepts test class as parameter.
//use ITestResult#getInstance()

private void getCurrentTestHelper(Object testClass) {
        Class<?> c = testClass.getClass();
        try {
            //get the field "h" declared in the test-class.
            //getDeclaredField() works for protected members.
            Field hField = c.getDeclaredField("h");

            //get the name and class of the field h.
            //(this is just for fun)
            String name = hField.getName();
            Object thisHelperInstance = hField.get(testClass);
            System.out.print(name + ":" + thisHelperInstance.toString() + "\n");

            //get fields inside this Helper as follows:
            Field innerField = thisHelperInstance.getClass().getDeclaredField("someInnerField");

            //get the value of the field corresponding to the above Helper instance.
            System.out.println(innerField.get(thisHelperInstance).toString());

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

Call this as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        getCurrentTestHelper(tr.getInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Vish 's solution is good, but you can avoid reflection with:

```
interface TestWithHelper {
   Helper getHelper();
}
```

where your `TestClass` will implement it.
Then:

```
private void getCurrentTestHelper(Object testClass) {
  if (testClass instanceof TestWithHelper) {
    Helper helper = ((TestWithHelper) testClass).getHelper();
    ...
  }
}
```