# Creating Solr schema based on a class using SolrJ

Tags: solr, solrj

On application startup I want to check if schema exists and:
1) if it doesn't -> create schema from Java class containing fields
2) if it differs for aforementioned class -> update the schema
3) if schema maps 1:1 with fields in Java class then do nothing

I've divided my task into 3 subtask and my first one would be to create a schema from existing Java class.

Here is my class (getters and setters omitted):

```
public class Order {
private String name;
private String phone;
private Address address;

private List<Amenities> amenities;
private BigDecimal distance;
private String image;
private List<Attributes> attributes;
private List<String> networks;
private OrderType orderType;
private Service service;
}
```

As you can see it has quite many field types which also should be used to create a schema (recursively?). Is it even possible to create a schema like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be quite simple to do:

First, you need to list all fields of the class, it could be achieved via [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3567409/2663985). After it, you should use [Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-ModifytheSchema), which will allow you to do CRUD operation on the fields for schema.

`/schema/fields` will allow you to get all fields, and then you could use `replace-field` for updating field, `delete-field` to a deletion of field and `add-field` for adding field. For more information just check this [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-ModifytheSchema).

Caveat: Schema API was added starting from Solr 5.3

Comment: Be aware that this will be hard to solve for any referenced extended objects (i.e. the `Amenities`, `Service`, `OrderType`, `Attributes` objects in his example), as parent/child relations in Solr requires great care when querying (especially outside of plain querying) and indexing (and more than a single level makes it even harder to get right for most features).

Comment: @MatsLindh, of course. I was somehow thinking it's a bit out of scope for this question

Comment: Thank you for your anwswer - added another question about SolrJ if you have a minute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308076/creating-enumtype-solr-using-solrj

Comment: @Mysterion Sure, just a warning to OP.