# Finding all attributes of composite class using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

I have requirement where in I will be given an object and I have to prepare a list of all the attributes in that object. The object can be a composite object. The idea is to get the list of all the attributes of type String, Integer, boolean and Date. There is a way to use reflection mechanism and doing this recursively. However, this can become quite complex. So I was just wondering, if there is any third party library that I can use.

Comment: attribute mean class property right ?

Comment: What is a 'class property'?  Classes have attributes in the class file spec (like what tells the compiler about generic parameters), do you mean those or javabeans getter/setter style properties?

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042798/retrieving-the-inherited-attribute-names-values-using-java-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). In particular [PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors()](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getPropertyDescriptors%28java.lang.Class%29). Caveat, this only works for fields with getters and setters.

You'd then have to call this recursively for each property descriptor you find in the parent class.