# Get all Fields of class hierarchy

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have classes:

```
ClassA{
 public String filedA;
}

ClassB extends ClassA{
 public String filedB;
}

ClassC extends ClassB{
 public String filedC;
}
```

Then I create object:

```
ClassC c=new ClassC();
c.fieldC="TestC";
c.fieldA="TestA";
c.fieldB="TestB";
```

After I try get all fields, I call

```
Field[] fields=c.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

But I get array with only one item

```
fields[fieldC]
```

How to get all fields from all classes include extends?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Field[] fields = c.getClass().getFields();
```

If you want all superclass fields, see the following:

[Retrieving the inherited attribute names/values using Java Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042798/retrieving-the-inherited-attribute-names-values-using-java-reflection)

Comment: Thanks, it's because using getDeclaredFields - return only current class fields, getFields return all include static, final and etc.

Comment: This simply doesn't answer the question anyhow

Comment: The drawback is, you can only find public fields with it.

Answer (score 7):

Your C class does not extend any class. Then, `getDeclaredFields()` only returns `String filedC` as you have seen. You cannot do `c.fieldA="TestA"` and `c.fieldB="TestB"` because your class does not declare this fields. Anyway, in case of C extends B and B extends A, method [getFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29) returns only public fields (including inherited):

> Returns an array containing Field objects reflecting all the accessible public fields of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

And [getDeclaredFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) returns all fields declared in the class (not including inherited):

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but excludes inherited fields.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel you could rely upon [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) version 3.2+ which provides [`FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html#getAllFieldsList(java.lang.Class)):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.AbstractCollection;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.AbstractSequentialList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FieldUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetAllFieldsList() {

        // Get all fields in this class and all of its parents
        final List<Field> allFields = FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList(LinkedList.class);

        // Get the fields form each individual class in the type's hierarchy
        final List<Field> allFieldsClass = Arrays.asList(LinkedList.class.getFields());
        final List<Field> allFieldsParent = Arrays.asList(AbstractSequentialList.class.getFields());
        final List<Field> allFieldsParentsParent = Arrays.asList(AbstractList.class.getFields());
        final List<Field> allFieldsParentsParentsParent = Arrays.asList(AbstractCollection.class.getFields());

        // Test that `getAllFieldsList` did truly get all of the fields of the the class and all its parents 
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsClass));
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsParent));
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsParentsParent));
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsParentsParentsParent));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work with reflection if `ClassC` derived from `ClassB` (and presumably from `ClassA` etc..). I assume this is a typo ? Then this:

```
Field[] fields = c.getClass().getFields();
```

would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`getDeclaredFields()` which you are using, are not contain inherited flields from superclass.

if you want all clields just use `getFields()` method

Comment: getFields() only returns _accessible_ fields! That means it only works in this particular question as he has his fields püublic.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get them with

```
Field[] fields = c.getClass().getFields();
```

This returns all accessible fields.