# How to create a generic datatype to access a inner parameter of a Json Response

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

If you look at the code below the ENERC_KCAL,FAT,FASAT,FAMS all of them has the same 3 parameters *label*, *quantity* and *unit*. I want to set the label and quantity value in my RecyclerAdapter to populate a recylerView.

```
"totalNutrients":{
   "ENERC_KCAL":{
      "label":"Energy",
      "quantity":2493.0949190757847,
      "unit":"kcal"
   },
   "FAT":{
      "label":"Fat",
      "quantity":2.275,
      "unit":"g"
   },
   "FASAT":{
      "label":"Saturated",
      "quantity":0.0665,
      "unit":"g"
   },
   "FAMS":{
      "label":"Monounsaturated",
      "quantity":0.224,
      "unit":"g"
   }
}
```

However, in my data class, is creating individual objects of type ENERC_KCAL,FAT,FASAT,FAMS(I'm using the Json to Kotlin Class Plugin) in the following format

```
                    data class ENERCKCAL(
                    @SerializedName("label")
                    val label: String?,
                    @SerializedName("quantity")
                    val quantity: Double?,
                    @SerializedName("unit")
                    val unit: String?
                )

                data class FAT(
                    @SerializedName("label")
                    val label: String?,
                    @SerializedName("quantity")
                    val quantity: Double?,
                    @SerializedName("unit")
                    val unit: String?
                )

                data class FASAT(
                    @SerializedName("label")
                    val label: String?,
                    @SerializedName("quantity")
                    val quantity: Double?,
                    @SerializedName("unit")
                    val unit: String?
                )
```

Is there a way to generate a GenericClass to access the label and quantity value or how do i access the values in the present structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to display your data in recyclerview, try this:

```
  data class TotalNutrients(@SerializedName("ENERC_KCAL")val enerc:Nutrient, @SerializedName("FAT")val fat:Nutrient, @SerializedName("FASAT")val fasat:Nutrient, @SerializedName("FAMS")val fams:Nutrient) {

        data class Nutrient(@SerializedName("label")
                            val label: String?,
                            @SerializedName("quantity")
                            val quantity: Double?,
                            @SerializedName("unit")
                            val unit: String?
        )
        
        fun getArrayList():ArrayList<Nutrient>{
            return arrayListOf(enerc,fat,fasat,fams)
        }

    }
```

Now you can use getArrayList() to populate a recyclerview

Comment: This works. However, in my project I have 45 elements just like ENERC_KCAL, etc. is there any alternative?

Comment: perhaps smth like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295949/get-all-fields-even-private-and-inherited-from-class

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution to the same problem in case you have a lot of similar data classes.

```
data class Nutrient(@SerializedName("label")
                            val label: String?,
                            @SerializedName("quantity")
                            val quantity: Double?,
                            @SerializedName("unit")
                            val unit: String?
        )
```

and in the upper data class define this as a

`val valuesOfNutrients:Map<String, Nutrient>`

then you can access all the elements using   `valuesOfNutrients.value`   without the need for the intermediate data classes