# How can I add these variables that share almost the same name without the need to add them line by line?

Tags: java

This is the class where I declare several INT variables that contain positions and then add them into an arraylist but I would like to do it in some kind of loop and not add line by line

```
class Ejecutar {

    
    private int B1 = 0;
    private int B2 = 2;
    private int B3 = 3;
    private int B4 = 8;
    private int B5 = 9;
    private int B6 = 11;
    private int B7 = 12;
    private int B8 = 17;

    
    private  ArrayList<Integer> arreglo_posiciones = new ArrList<Integer>();

    
    public Ejecutar() {
        
    }
    
    
    public void cargarArregloPosiciones() { 
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B1);
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B2);
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B3);
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B4);
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B5);
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B6);
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B7);
        this.arreglo_posiciones.add(this.B8); 
    }

}
```

I want to add these variables with some kind of loop without the need to add them line by line

Comment: Do you need the positions as class members? or can you directly put them into the array?

Comment: this might help you building a List of the fields of the class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295949/get-all-fields-even-private-and-inherited-from-class

Comment: Yes, as @Stultuske you can use *reflection* to solve your problem, there is no other way except if you want to change your logic.

Comment: @Stultuske Do you have any idea if it loads the array sequentially to the variables? That is, I would add how I have it in the code, right?

Comment: try writing the code and find out