# merging one object into another object

Tags: java

I have two Objects of same type.I want to create a method which can merge the properties of two object and can return a single object.

For Example:
Consider a class ABC having 4 fields

```
Class ABC{
String name;
String id;
String salary;
String status;
}
```

Suppose the first object is

```
ABC[name=ZEE,id=2,salary=null,status=1]
```

and the second object is

```
ABC[name=john,id=null,salary=12200,status=null]
```

I want to make a generic method which can merge these two objects and can give result output as:

```
ABC[name=ZEE,id=2,salary=12200,status=1]
```

The method Should take two parameters of Object type:

```
Object  mergeObject(Object Obj1, Object Obj2){
}
```

Note: It will take the first object property if both the objects have non-null value for that property.

Comment: what happened to `john`

Comment: How will you handle collisions? e.g. `Obj1` has a field and so does `Obj2`. Depending on that logic, just setup some accessor/mutator (getter/setter) methods for the class variables and in your `mergeObject` method, create a new object and set fields as you go by checking `Obj1` vs. `Obj2`

Comment: Generic as "will work for all objects"? This is not going to be possible. Consider enums, for example. Even getting close will require some serious reflection stunts.

Comment: And what have you done so far yourself? Besides writing up this question? You understand you don't just drop your requirements here; and other people do your work?

Comment: This isn't genericity, and this isn't good programming

Comment: Seriously, **what happened to** `john` as a name on collision? The second object's value was overridden.... is this intended behavior?

Comment: It will take the first object property if both the objects have non-null value for that property.

Comment: @jsonwilczak that is not generic one

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're going to have to go the reflection route. I'm assuming you **have a default constructor**, otherwise the following won't work. Also, it needs two same types. It won't copy inherited fields, for that, you also need to add some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042827/2413303).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T mergeObjects(T first, T second) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class<?> clazz = first.getClass();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    Object returnValue = clazz.newInstance();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value1 = field.get(first);
        Object value2 = field.get(second);
        Object value = (value1 != null) ? value1 : value2;
        field.set(returnValue, value);
    }
    return (T) returnValue;
}
```

Here's an example

```
public static class ABC {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int[] numbers;

    public ABC() {
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int[] getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumbers(int[] numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    ABC abc = new ABC();
    abc.setId(1);
    abc.setName("Hello");
    int[] newnumbers = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < newnumbers.length; i++) {
        newnumbers[i] = i;
    }
    abc.setNumbers(newnumbers);
    ABC abc2 = new ABC();
    abc2.setName("World");

    ABC abcFinal = mergeObjects(abc, abc2);
    System.out.println("Properties of ABC Final:");
    System.out.println("ID: " + abcFinal.getId());
    System.out.println("Name: " + abcFinal.getName());
    System.out.println("Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(abcFinal.getNumbers()));
}
```

Output:

```
Properties of ABC Final:
ID: 1
Name: Hello
Numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @Dici is this what he wanted?

Comment: This is perfect I was writing program to give answer, but you have posted first @Epic :) Good Job

Comment: @EpicPandaForce seems to be the case :)

Comment: epic answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to create a new Object use:

```
public ABC mergeABC(ABC obj1, ABC obj2){
    ABC retVal = new ABC();
    retVal.name   = ((obj1.name   != null) ? obj1.name   : obj2.name   );
    retVal.id     = ((obj1.id     != null) ? obj1.id     : obj2.id     );
    retVal.salary = ((obj1.salary != null) ? obj1.salary : obj2.salary );
    retVal.status = ((obj1.status != null) ? obj1.status : obj2.status );
    return retVal;
}
```

If you want to "reuse" obj1 or obj2, simply use this as return value.

Comment: This is the most sensible answer so far, however it does not answer the question. You should clearly start saying why what the OP wants is hard and bad, and then present this more sensible (and different) solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prioritize the values in Object 1 (in case both objects have values), then follow something like this..

```
private CustomObject mergeObject(CustomObject Obj1, CustomObject Obj2) {
    CustomObject tempObject = new CustomObject();
     If (Obj1.getName() == null) {
      tempObject.setName(Obj2.getName());
     } else {
         tempObject.setName(Obj1.getName());
     }
     return tempObject;
}
```

Iterate over the if statement for each parameter within the object.

Comment: Is this a new language ? It seems pretty cool, unfortunately the qustion is for Java

Comment: I don't get it.. it's probably not the best solution but it does work - in java. Obviously "Object" would be a custom object, and not the word "object"

Comment: "obviously" if you just say `Object`, people will say it's a compile time error.

Comment: @Dici  EpicPandaForce I changed my answer... hopefully it's a bit better.

Comment: Oh yeah obviously, so don't use the name of the most famous class of Java to name another custom class

Comment: Sorry - I fixed my answer.

Comment: @Othya You are still missing several brackets and you are still using `Object` for one of your parameters.

Comment: @Dici thanks, I edited again.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do it generically, your only option is going to be reflection.

Comment: That's more suitable as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: 'Use reflection' is a reasonable answer...not every answer has to be spoon fed code?