# Design pattern compatible with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have some code that relies on reflection (working with a third-party libarary) to get the fields of a class. Many of these classes use a mix of the same fields, some nearly identical but with a few differences.

This has led to a ton of code duplication, but I'm not sure of a nice pattern around it due to the reliance reflection.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()):

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but **excludes inherited fields**.

This rules out an Abstract class or any inheritence-related solutions.

Here's a code example (`MyField` represents a third-party library object, and `myData` is a public member of `MyField`):

**ClassA.java**

```
public class ClassA {
    private final Field[] myFields;

    private final MyField a = new MyField(1);
    private final MyField b = new MyField(2);
    private final MyField c = new MyField(3);

    public ClassA() {
        myFields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    }

    public void doStuff(Field[] myFields) {
        // As an example, this clears out the field values.
        // There are several of these methods that use or manipulate the fields
        for (Field f : myFields) {
            if (f.getType() == MyField.class
                || f.getType().getSuperclass() == MyField.class) {
                try {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    ((MyField) f.get(this)).myData.reset();
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Field[] getFields() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(myFields, myFields.length);
    {
}
```

**ClassB.java**

```
public class ClassB {
    private final Field[] myFields;

    private final MyField a = new MyField(1);
    private final MyField c = new MyField(3);
    private final MyField d = new MyField(4);

    public ClassB() {
        myFields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    }

    public void doStuff(Field[] myFields) {
        // Same as above
    }

    public Field[] getFields() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(myFields, myFields.length);
    {
}
```

Note that `ClassA` and `ClassB` share fields `a` and `c` and methods `getFields()` and `doStuff()`.

Is there any way to shore up some of this duplication without affecting the reflection?

Comment: Those are your classes? Why are they declaring those as fields in the first place? They should probably be in a `Map` and save you the whole reflection thing. You should probably add some of the things `doStuff` does with those fields to clarify the issue.

Comment: Updated with sample code in `doStuff()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do the fields need to be stored in an array within the class? It seems that `obj.getFields()` is always equivalent to `obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`. Note that `getDeclaredFields` returns a new array each time anyway, so calling it once and then making a defensive copy on your own getter is superfluous.

If you prefer the readability of `obj.getFields()` then you could make this a [default interface method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), and inherit it on each class from the interface without having to change the class hierarchy:

```java
public interface FieldGetter {
    default Field[] getFields() {
        return this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    }
}
```

Example:

```java
> class A implements FieldGetter { int x; String y; }
> new A().getFields()
Field[2] { int A.x, java.lang.String A.y }
```

It's not clear whether your `doStuff` method does the same thing on each class; if so, you can make that a default interface method, too.

By the way, the fact that `getDeclaredFields` doesn't return superclass fields isn't a barrier to having a class hierarchy, because you can call it on the superclasses too; see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042798/retrieving-the-inherited-attribute-names-values-using-java-reflection).

Comment: Yes, `doStuff()` is the same in all classes. I was thinking I may be able to move this to a Util class, but the Interface may be better. Thanks for the superclass tip! I'm going to set up a test and see if this works.